# Unsigned Int to Void* and then Back

Tags: c, pointers

I have an unsigned int where I am using each of the 32 bits to store a specific piece of information..

```
function( void * a);
unsigned int val = 0xFFFFFFFF;
function( (void *) (long) val );
```

Within the function, I want to modify the unsigned int.. I can't figure out how to uncast it without losing precision or any of the bits. Is tjere a correct way to do this.. can't seem to figure it out..

Comment: `int` is not guaranteed to have 32 bits. If you need a fixed width type, use one from `stdint.h`.

Comment: What is your problem? Why all the casting? Why use `void *`? Never use `void *` if it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What are you doing and what goes wrong? Why the `(long)` cast is there?

Comment: @Olaf unfortunatly in this case for the interface i have to :(

Comment: yeah i shouldn't have been casting to long, I am just trying to figure out how I can pass in an unsigned int in as a void * and then use it again as a void *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the address of val to the function by casting in to a void* like this:

```
function((void*)&val);
```

and design your function like:

```
void function(void* ptr) {
    unsigned int *p = (unsigned int*)ptr;
    (*p)++; //example of a change
}
```

Comment: is there anyway I can cast into an unsigned int instead of a long?

Comment: does that answer your question?